# Spring Boot spring-boot:build-image: how to configure direct memory (MaxDirectMemorySize)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, paketo

I use the spring-boot:build-image maven target for building a docker image of my Spring Boot application. I have following setup in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:full</builder>
            <runImage>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run:full-cnb</runImage>
            <env>
                <BP_JVM_VERSION>17</BP_JVM_VERSION>
                <JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64M</JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>
            </env>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I change the MaxDirectMemorySize? The JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment doesn't work. I still get following console log output on startup:

```
Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx1310134K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=275017K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 2G, Thread Count: 250, Loaded Class Count: 46141, Headroom: 0%)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=4 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx1310134K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=275017K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
```

How can I increase the max direct memory size? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [`BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS`](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/native-image) work?

Comment: No, BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS is for creating native images, but I build a docker image with jvm. As far as I understand the BP_ prefixed environment variables changes the behaviour on build and not runtime.

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't worry too much about single downvotes. In this case, I think someone might have been thinking it needed details/clarity in some way (though that might not have been the same person).

Comment: @dan1stiscrying ah okay, thanks a lot for clarification. I just wondered...

Comment: @Tobi I think that adding the spring-boot version would have been helpful.
I assumed 3+ in my suggested answer because of the paketo integration but I might have been wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to apply a runtime configuration (JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS) to build informations.

According to the spring documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.runtime-jvm-configuration, you should change this to.

```
        <env>
            <BP_JVM_VERSION>17</BP_JVM_VERSION>
            <BPE_APPEND_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64M</BPE_APPEND_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>
        </env>
```

Does that make it work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. But you also need to add
<BPE_DELIM_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS xml:space="preserve"> </BPE_DELIM_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>
otherwise you get the error
"Unrecognized VM option 'ExitOnOutOfMemoryError-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64M'"
because of the missing space.